# Unable to connect to VPC public subnet EC2 instance using SSH or Ping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, subnet, aws-security-group

I have created a VPC which has 2 subnet public and private.

I have created Public and Private  route tables and attached to private subnet and public subnet .

Also i have added the ACL and inbound rules ( attached in screenshot ) and attached it to both subnets .

Launched EC2 instance and attached one with private subnet and one with public subnet and also attached security group which has all traffic allow in inbound rules.

I am unable to connect to EC2 instance using public ip:

ping 15.XXX.XXX.XXX

ssh -i "vpctest.pem" ubuntu@15.XXX.XXXX.XXX

which is connected to public subnet via SSH and also unable to ping it from my laptop. Please help.

[Public Route Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RttCU.png)

[Private Route Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBjH7.png)

[Network ACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAA96.png)
[VPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3cqg.png)

[Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DebBV.png)

[Public Subnet Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jyId.png)

[Public Subnet Route Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Ab8.png)

[Public Subnet ACL Association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuaIC.png)

[EC2 Public instance details ][10]

Comment: As far as I can tell, you didn't include your security group inbound rules or your ACL outbound rules.

Comment: I have attached security group in EC2 instance and included inbound rules. And i have attached the ACL to VPC .

Comment: What are your security group inbound rules?

Comment: Can your confirm any additional information for the public instance?

Comment: What is the error and behavior? is it just hanging(timeout) or connection refused or something else?

Comment: @shawn.  SG Inbound rules is all traffic allow from anywhere

Comment: @congbaoguieri it is timed out .

Comment: Does your public subnet have an internet gateway?

Comment: Yes ,it is attached to internet gateway, I have attached screenshot also

Comment: @AllTech Did you manage to resolve this problem?

Comment: No, i didn't get the result yet.